Bandwidth use with vnstat and bridge device - how do they add up?
I use vnstat to monitor bandwidth and generate alerts if needed. In a test setup I have eth0 and a wlan combined in a single subnet under bridge lan-br0. When running traffic tests I would expect the traffic totals for lan-br0 to equal wlan0+eth0, but that is not the case.
In the test example below I continuously ping the server via wlan0 to generate traffic, and eth0 is disconnected (no traffic). I get this data:
        RX  TX  TOT
WLAN    106,465 67,604  174,070
        90,634  59,873  150,497
        85,473  52,808  138,281
        87,040  55,398  142,438

and:
        RX  TX  TOT
BR      45,978  75,776  121,743
        32,891  67,656  100,547
        30,986  60,099  91,085
        31,795  63,037  94,843

The eth0 data is all zeros. The difference (BR-WLAN):
        RX      TX      TOT
BR-WLAN -60,488 8,172   -52,326
        -57,743 7,782   -49,951
        -54,487 7,291   -47,196
        -55,245 7,639   -47,596

As you can see this does not add up. Where does the rest go / come from?
Note:

I set MaxBandwidth=0 in /etc/vnstat.conf

Update:
I repeated experiments with larger data transfers (sending files with scp), and the discprepancies are relatively smaller, but still present.
